# Solr sort functions min works not like max?

Tags: solr

I want to order the Products to wheter a specific word is in the name and then to popularity. All Products that have the word in the name should be displayed first ordered to popularity. This Query should do the job:

http://cedesrv16:8983/solr/db/select/?q=qual&sort=min%28query%28{!v=%22name:qual%22}%29,1%29%20desc,popularity%20desc

But this error is shown:  Can't determine Sort Order: 'min(query({!v="name:qual"}),1) desc,popularity desc', pos=3

The strange thing is: when i do exactly the same query with a max instead of a min, it works correctly:

http://cedesrv16:8983/solr/db/select/?q=qual&sort=max%28query%28{!v=%22name:qual%22}%29,1%29%20desc,popularity%20desc

What do I do wrong? Is there a better way to do the sort?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my problem. I subtract the ranking of 1 and take the max.

http://cedesrv16:8983/solr/db/select/?q=qual&sort=max%28sub%281,query%28{!v=%22name:qual%22}%29%29,0%29%20asc,popularity%20desc